# Программа проверяющая , является число палиндромом , при вводе 54045 выдает что это не палиндром?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {0};
    int b[5];

        printf("Enter a five-digit number: ");
        for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        {
            scanf("%i",&a[i]);
        }
        for(int j = 0;j < 5;j++)
        {
            b[j] = a[5 - 1 - j];
        }

        if(a == b)
        {
            printf("This number is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("This number is not a palindrome");
        }
}
```

Comment: Это C или C++? Выберите один язык, это может влиять на ответ.

Comment: Думаю, проблема в том как сравниваются массивы, а именно `a == b` не кажется мне правильным

Comment: Этот пример всегда будет выдавать, что число не палиндром. `a == b` сравнит два указателя, и они не равны по их определению в примере - это два разных участка памяти на стеке.

Comment: А вообще палиндром лучше искать через строку гораздо удобней если использовать stl то функцию можно так написать                                  
bool Palindrom(const string& p) {
    return equal(p.begin(), p.end(), p.rbegin());
}

Comment: @Ecko: А при чем здесь строка вообще? Такой подход применим напрямую к исходным массивам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int main() {
    int a[5] = {0};
    bool flag = true;
        printf("Enter a five-digit number: ");
        for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        {
            scanf("%i",&a[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0, j = 4; i < j; i++, j--)
        {
           if (a[i] != a[j]) {
              flag = false;
              break;
           }
        }

        if(flag)
        {
            printf("This number is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("This number is not a palindrome");
        }
}
```

Comment: Для чего ответ, если вопроса не было. Может вопрос  должен звучать так:  " Как написать программу для чисел с произвольным количеством цифр"?  ТС подумал, что мы должны угодать содержание вопроса или просто забыл ...

Comment: Всё моя невнимательность=) и вправду не просил написать

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Как сказали на английском сайте, СО кончно хорошо угадывает мысли ОП, но лучше чтоб вопрос все-таки был бы. Однако он есть, в заголовке.

Comment: Можно еще проще. Написать сообщение об отрицательном резутате внутри  цикла и выйти из функции.  Завершение цикла означает положительный результат.

Answer (score 0):

Как должен звучать ваш вопрос: так "в чем ошибка в программе, которая проверяет является ли число полиндромом ?" или еще по другому, но задавайте вопрос четко.  В любом случаи стоит написать класс чисел и добавлять в нем полезные(для вас)  методы, и он будет служить для вас и мини библиотекой и местом для тренировки. Я приведу пример:

```
class Number {      
    long n;
public:
    Number(long num = 0) : n(num){}
    // вот количестов цифр в нем
    size_t number_of_digits() const
    {       
        size_t i{1};
        for (long d = 10; n >= d; d *= 10)  ++i;        
        return i;
    }
    // вот строковое представление 
    std::string str() const
    {
        return std::to_string(n);
    }
    //вот преобразование    
    operator long() { return n; }   
    /* допишите другие функции_члены,   
       что считаете полезным.
       Например, как использовать эти методы
       для решения вашей задачи: */
    bool is_palindrome() const {
        std::string s1(str()),
            s2(s1.rbegin(), s1.rend());
        const size_t k = number_of_digits() / 2;
        return s1.substr(0, k) == s2.substr(0, k);
    }
};

int main() {    
    Number k(23432);
    cout << k.number_of_digits() << '\n'
        << k << '\n' << k.str() << '\n'
        << std::boolalpha << k.is_palindrome();
    return 0;
}
```